# Reflection check if parameterized type is String and Object

Tags: java, generics, reflection, parameterized-types

I am having an issue when checking parameterized types of a parameter.

I am using `method.getGenericParameterTypes()` and casting it to `ParameterizedType` simply to check if the parameter is the correct `Map` however when I check the types I get `String, ?` instead of `String, Object`, for the string it's easy to check with `String.class.equals(type[0])` however for `?` doing `Object.class.equals(type[1])` will return false.

Is there a better way to check if the parameterized type is `Object`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameterized type *is* `?`, not Object. These are not at all the same thing.

You can call `map.put("Hello", new Object());` on a `Map<String, Object>`. It is not possible to call `map.put` *at all* on a `Map<String, ?>`<sup>*</sup>.

You can pass an expression of type `Map<String, Integer>` as a parameter to a method, if it wants a `Map<String, ?>`. You can't pass a `Map<String, Object>`. You also can't pass a `Map<String, Integer>` to a method that wants a `Map<String, Object>` (because if you could, you can then put a `new Object()` in there, and break everything).

Note furthermore that your plan is very fragile and doesn't cover most of the cases that generics are trying to cover. For example, if you have a:

```
public class Foo<T> {
    private final Map<T, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Then for, say, `new Foo<String>()`, the map is in fact the one you wanted, but your check will find `T`, which obviously isn't String. Generics aren't reified. You can't hack around it with `.getGenericType()` - whatever you're trying to do is probably never going to work and you need to rethink your approach.

A `?` will be an instance of `WildcardType`; cast it to that, then ask for the lower bounds. Object should be amongst them (for just `?`, that'll be the only lower bound, in fact). There's not a lot you can do other than do an instanceof check for all the many different kinds of types that exist and write custom code for each and every one. You'll find that your question ('can I pass `new Object()` without breaking things, for example') is unanswerable for some of these, such as when it's an instance of `java.lang.reflect.TypeVariable`.

*) Except for the academic case of `map.put("Hello", null);` which is surely the desired call to make.

Comment: Apologies I don't think I explained well my problem, basically i have the following method `public Object test(final Map<String, Object> map) ` I am trying to check if the method's parameter is `Map<String, Object>` but what I get from reflection is `Map<String, ?>`.

Comment: See? I told you you can't do what you want. You're inspecting the type of the parameter, not of the object being passed in. That one really is `?`. __Generics are erased at runtime__ - what you want is not possible.

Comment: Actually I found my issue, I was testing in Kotlin and `Any` turns into wildcard while `Object` is fine. Will have to do both, thank you!